Projecting the initial state on a Discontinuous Galerkin basis
Context
I want to solve a 1D Burgers equation with a discontinuous Galerkin approach on the space-time domain $(x,t)\in [0,1]^2$. I want to project the function $u(x) = e^{-\frac{(x-0.5)^2}{0.02}}$ over basis functions. The choosen basis are normalized Legendre polynomials.
The DG representation of the initial state is then:
$$u^{DG}(x) = \sum_k <\phi_k, u> \phi_k(x)$$ with test function $\phi_k$, the dot product $<f,g> = \int_{\Omega} f(x)g(x)dx$ and $\Omega = [0,1]$ the full space domain.
Problem
To answer the above problem, integrals need to be computed. For every test function $v$ (defined over the physical domain $[a,b]\in [0,1]$ not the reference one) and its associated test function over the reference element $\hat{v}$, I want to compute:
$$
\begin{align}
\int_a^b u(x) v(x)dx &= \frac{b-a}{2}\int_{-1}^1 u(f^{-1}(y)) \hat{v}(y)dy
= \frac{b-a}{2}\sum_k w_k u(f^{-1}(y_k)) \hat{v}(y_k)
\end{align}
$$
The first equality is obtained with the variable substitution $y = f(x) = \frac{2(x-a)}{b-a}-1$. The second one is obtained by using a Gauss-Legendre quadrature scheme on $[-1,1]$ with weights $w_k$ and abscissas $x_k$. By using the above formulae, I do not get a good projection of the initial state over the Galerkin basis. But when I remove the $\frac{b-a}{2}$ factor the results look right. I do not get what I did wrong in the integration. The results can be seen by running the code below. Do not hesitate to ask for clarifications.
Prolematic snippet
# dot product over reference element /!\ jacobian missing
    U[ie*p + i] += np.sum(weightQuadrature*u0(xPhysical)*basisFunctionOnQuadraturePointArray[i])

    # supposed to work
    #U[ie*p + i] += J*np.sum(weightQuadrature*u0(xPhysical)*basisFunctionOnQuadraturePointArray[i])

Results with 5 elements and a quadratic polynomial basis
With the "correct" quadrature scheme:

By removing the Jacobian of the transformation from the physical domain to the reference element (removing the factor):

Full Code
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

############
# reference element + quadrature
############
x1ref, x2ref = -1.0, 1.0
QuadratureRule = np.array([
    [0.3607615730481386,    0.6612093864662645],
    [0.3607615730481386,    -0.6612093864662645],
    [0.4679139345726910,    -0.2386191860831969],
    [0.4679139345726910,    0.2386191860831969],
    [0.1713244923791704,    -0.9324695142031521],
    [0.1713244923791704,    0.9324695142031521],
])
xQuadrature = QuadratureRule[:,1]
weightQuadrature = QuadratureRule[:,0]
nQuadrature = len(QuadratureRule)

del(QuadratureRule)

def integrateOnReferenceElement(func):
  return integrateOnReferenceElement_(func, weightQuadrature, xQuadrature)

def integrateOnReferenceElement_(func, weightQuadrature, xQuadrature):
  return np.sum(weightQuadrature*func(xQuadrature))
############
# basis functions definition (Legendre)
############
p = locdim = 3
basisFunctionArray = [
         np.polynomial.legendre.Legendre([0]*i+[1]) for i in range(p)
]

# normalizing the basis functions
for i in range(p):
  new_coeff = 0.0

  basisFunctionI = basisFunctionArray[i]

  def basisFunctionI_2(x):
    return basisFunctionI(x)**2

  norm_2 = integrateOnReferenceElement(basisFunctionI_2)
  new_coeff = 1/np.sqrt(norm_2)
  basisFunctionArray[i].coef[-1] = new_coeff

  norm_2 = integrateOnReferenceElement(basisFunctionI_2)
  assert np.isclose(norm_2,1)

# saving values of basis functions on quadrature points
basisFunctionOnQuadraturePointArray = []

for i in range(p):
    basisFunctionOnQuadraturePointArray.append(basisFunctionArray[i](xQuadrature))

basisFunctionOnQuadraturePointArray = np.stack(basisFunctionOnQuadraturePointArray, axis=0)

############
# space mesh
############
nElt = 10
nPts = nElt + 1
X = np.linspace(0, 1, nPts)
elementConnectivityArray = np.array([[i, i+1] for i in range(nPts-1)])

############
# project initial state on basis
############
def u0(x):
  return np.exp(-(x-0.5)**2/0.02)

nDof = p * nElt

# vector representation of u0 in the discontinuous Galerkin basis
U = np.zeros(nDof)

for ie in range(nElt):
  tag1, tag2 = elementConnectivityArray[ie]
  x1, x2 = X[tag1], X[tag2]
  l = np.abs(x2-x1)

  # jacobian of the transformation from the real domain to reference element
  J = l/2

  # quadrature points on the real/physical space
  xPhysical = l * (xQuadrature + 1)/2 + x1

  for i in range(p):
    # dot product over reference element /!\ jacobian missing
    U[ie*p + i] += np.sum(weightQuadrature*u0(xPhysical)*basisFunctionOnQuadraturePointArray[i])

    # supposed to work
    #U[ie*p + i] += J*np.sum(weightQuadrature*u0(xPhysical)*basisFunctionOnQuadraturePointArray[i])

############
# plotting result function
############
x_test = np.linspace(-1,1, 10)

for ie in range(nElt):
  tag1, tag2 = elementConnectivityArray[ie]
  x1, x2 = X[tag1], X[tag2]
  l = np.abs(x2-x1)
  J = l/2
  xReal = l * (x_test + 1)/2 + x1
  yReal = 0.0

  # representation over the local element
  for i in range(p):
    yReal = yReal + U[ie*p + i] * basisFunctionArray[i](x_test)
  plt.plot(xReal, yReal, c='r')

x_ = np.linspace(0,1, 1000)

plt.plot(x_, u0(x_), label='initial state', c='b', linestyle='--')
plt.legend()



Can you add some details or results/plots as to how the results differ when this change is made in your code?

Why not start with a simpler function, say trying to project a constant function onto your finite element space.

@WolfgangBangerth From the images, where the function is close to zero (almost constant), the approximation is pretty good. The error is mostly in my understanding and derivation of the quadrature scheme.

Approximating zero is not all that difficult. Approximating a function that is constant one turns out to be much harder.

Your reconstruction looks ~$1/10$ the height it should be and your elements have length $0.1$. I suspect you are accidentally multiplying by the element length twice

The projection problem was wrongly formulated. It should be as follow
$$\left\langle u_{DG},v_{test} \right\rangle= \left\langle u, v_{test}\right\rangle \quad \forall v_{test}\, .$$
Then it will introduce a linear system to solve for the coefficients involving the mass matrix and the RHS being the dot products of the initial state with each $v_{test}$.
Since my polynomial basis was orthogonal and normalized, it is equivalent to apply the quadrature scheme without the factor (jacobian).
